# How can I prevent Time Machine encryption speed from dropping while leaving my Mac unattended?

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra, external-disk, encryption

I’m setting up a new disk for Time Machine, which is currently being encrypted. I’ve noticed that the encryption speed drops when leaving my Mac unattended; is there anything I can do to prevent this speed drop?

I used the Terminal command `diskutil corestorage list` to check the “Conversion Progress”. Initially this seemed to advance by at least 1% per hour. But then when I left it running overnight, it had only advanced by 3% the next morning.

Taking a closer look using the command `iostat -w 60 -d disk2`, I see that the “MB/s” drops from about 32 to 6 after 5 minutes of leaving my Mac unattended. Pressing a key on the keyboard suffices to bring it back up to 32.

What’s the cause of this speed drop? Is there any setting I can change to prevent it?

I should note that the Mac is an older one (13" MacBook Air, late 2010 model) with USB 2 ports and running macOS High Sierra.

Comment: not a setting, but you can script a little code to hit keystrokes in a file with a delay of say 2 minutes. You can delete the file later.

Comment: @ankii: thanks for the suggestion. I tried running the following command to simulate a press of the ‘return’ key after 6 minutes, but it didn't bring the speed back up (whereas me physically pressing ‘return’ does bring it back up to 32): `sleep $((6 * 60)); osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke return'`. I’m not sure whether there’s another way I could try this which would have the desired effect.

Comment: Open a txt file and type some letter?